# Magento 2 - Shopping cart items order

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, cart, shopping-cart, reorder

I am trying to **reorder** the sections on my **shopping cart page**.

This is what I currently have:
[image]

And this is what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

[image]
I need to add the **cart totals** inside *`\my-theme\Magento_Checkout\templates\cart\form.phtml`* before cart main actions buttons.

Comment: Both images are same.

Comment: They are not. The order of the buttons and subtotal is different.

Comment: I am not seeing any difference. Buttons are same on both images and also the subtotal

Comment: I edited my question with a more explicit picture.

Comment: Yes now its understandable.